# Prove that no disconnected region exists

Tags: graph-theory

> Ten points in space, no three of which are collinear, are connected, each oneto all the others, by a total of $45$ line segments. The resulting framework $F$ will be “disconnected” into two disjoint nonempty parts by the removal of one point from the interior of each of the 9 segments emanating from any one vertex off. Prove that $F$ cannot be similarly disconnected by the removal of only $8$ points from the interiors of the 45 segments.

I thought it was simple to prove this since you must disconnect at least $9$ segments in order to disconnect a vertex.

Comment: But disconnecting one vertex is not as general as disconnecting into two disjoint parts (which could be of any sizes, say 2 and 8...or 3 and 7). You are assuming that the split has to be into ones of size 1 and 9 (it does, but you should show why I think).

Comment: In order to disconnect into disjoint parts we must disconnect a vertex, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily...look at the graphs [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/BarbellGraph_875.gif).  The center edge can be deleted and disconnect the graph.

Comment: So that is the only exception then. I must show it doesn't have a center vertex?

Comment: I am confused can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Let there be $n$ points, to generalize on the $n=10$ case of the post. Suppose we remove a number of edges, so as to create a result having $k>1$ connected components remaining. If the sizes of the components are $a_1,a_2,\cdots a_k$ then how many edges do we need to remove to do this? For each ordered pair $(s,t)$ with $1 \le s<t\le k,$ we must remove each of the $a_sa_t$ edges which connect a vertex in the component going with size $a_s$ to another vertex in the component going with size $a_t.$ So in all we must remove at least
$$\sum_{s<t} a_sa_t$$
edges. We can get a lower bound for this by only using the pairs which have $a_1$ in them, that is, the above sum is at least
$$a_1a_2+a_1a_3+\cdots +a_1a_k=a_1(n-a_1),$$
the last because $a_1+a_2+ \cdots +a_k=n.$

Now we need to note that the minimal value of $a_1(n-a_1)$ occurs when $a_1=1$ or $a_1=n-1$ and is $n-1.$ The upshot is that, no matter how we delete edges so as to create a result having more than one connected component, we must in all cases remove at least $n-1$ edges to do it. Applied to $n=10$ case it shows we need to delete at least nine edges.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we want to show that to cut a complete Graph on n (here 10) vertices into disjoint pieces we need to remove at least n-1 edges.

---

Say we have removed m edges and cut the graph into disjoint pieces. Then there are 2 vertices $a_1, a_n$ so that the graph without those edges (let's call it G) doesn't contain a path between the two. 
Now we look at the n-1 paths of the form

$a_1 a_n, a_1 a_2 a_n, a_1 a_3 a_n, ... , a_1 a_{n-1} a_n$

These paths are all contained in our original graph (it was complete) and no two of them share any edges. for $a_1$ and $a_n$ to be disconnected in G we must have removed at least one edge in each of the paths, so m >= n-1

Comment: Paths $a_1a_2a_n$ and $a_1a_2a_3a_n$ share edge $a_1a_2$.

Comment: whoops sorry, fixed it, meant to be $a_1 a_2 a_n, a_1 a_3 a_n ...$